# I want to apply cosine similarity between two columns of strings and obtain their count in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames a (data file) and b (reference), of which I need to compare answer column, apply cosine similarity, obtain a dataframe with best matching values and their cosine. Later, I need count of each answer of b present in a (based on best matching values obtained after cosine similarity).

```
 a <- data.frame(Answer = c("Hey <firstname>, here are some topics I have been helping folks", 
                            "here are some topics I have been helping folks, have a nice day,<
                            "hello there, here are some topics I have been helping folks",
                             "Your final job decisions post the cycle will be available on this site",
                            "Compensation details will be sent on mail. Final job decisions post the cycle will be available on this link, have a great day"))

 b <- data.frame(Answer = c("here are some topics I have been helping folks,"Final Rewards decisions post the cycle will be available here","reward decisions post the cycle will be available on this link, have a great day"))
```

Expected output:

```
  Result = data.frame(Answer = c("here are some topics I have been helping folks,"Final Rewards decisions post the cycle will be available here"),count=c(3,2))
```

Comment: Where is your attempted code with errors/undesired results?

Comment: d.matrix <- stringdistmatrix(a = b$Answer, b = a$Answer, useNames="strings",method="cosine", nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread"))

    cosines<-apply(d.matrix, 2, min)

    #return list of the row number of the minimum value
    minlist<-apply(d.matrix, 2, which.min) 

    #return list of best matching values
    matchwith<-b$Answer[minlist]

Comment: After this, how to get count of each answer of b present in a (based on best matching values obtained after cosine similarity).

Comment: Please edit your post with attempted code and any supporting explanation and not in comments.

Comment: Is this a job for `table`? As in `as.data.frame(table(droplevels(matchwith)))`.